# Remove file extension with .htaccess: Error with trailing slash

Tags: html, .htaccess, file-extension

I want to remove the file extension like .html from my websites with .htaccess. The final structure should be like so:

```
http://domain.com/file  --> http://domain.com/file.html
http://domain.com/file/ --> http://domain.com/file.html
```

With my existing code in .htaccess I'll get "Internal Server Error" on my Browser when there's a trailing slash at the end. What can I do? Thanks!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your RewriteCond :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule  ^(.*)(\.html){0}$ /$1.html [L]
```

EDIT : rule edited, I forgot infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have still an error when there's a trailing slash at the end. It works fine when there's no slash.