# Remove PHP file extension AND trailing slash using MAMP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mamp

I am trying to remove file extensions and trailing slashes from the URI's I'm using as I rebuild my site.  I realize that removing the trailing slashes from URLs which actually rely on folders is ridiculous, but I need to preserve the existing URL structure that was created when the site was built in a home made CMS years ago.

I've read through the following and many more.

[Remove file extension with .htaccess: Error with trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036848/remove-file-extension-with-htaccess-error-with-trailing-slash)

[Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

**It seems that people like to answer the first part of the question (re. removing PHP) over and over and skip the 2nd part (also removing the trailing slash).**

I am able to remove PHP (or HTML for that matter) file extensions, but am unable to remove both the PHP file extensions and the trailing slashes for directories.

I am using MAMP and working on a mac with OS X El Capitan v. 10.11.6.

Here are the three URIs I need in order to confirm that this is working:

- /localhost/
- /localhost/about
- /localhost/about/guarantee

First, I tried to make /localhost/ and /localhost/about work.

In my root directory, I have the following files:

- index.php
- about.php

I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

When I browse to /localhost/, I get the home page.

When I browse to /localhost/about, I get the desired result - the about page with no file extension or trailing slash.

I.e., it works so far.

In order to make /localhost/about/guarantee work, I created a subfolder in the root:

- index.php
- about.php
- /about/guarantee.php

Unfortunately, when I try to visit /localhost/about now, the browser redirects to /about/ and shows:

> Index of /about
>
> Parent Directory
>
> guarantee.php

I.e., I can no longer get to /localhost/about.

I can get to /localhost/about/guarantee though.

So, I try rearranging the files. I add an index.php file to the /localhost/about/ folder:

- index.php
- about.php
- /about/index.php
- /about/guarantee.php

I am now able to visit /localhost/ and /localhost/about/ (WITH THE TRAILING SLASH) and /localhost/about/guarantee.

I cannot find a solution that will remove the trailing slash from /localhost/about/.

I would love some help with my .htaccess file.

Comment: A simple google search would have provided an answer

Comment: It would seem.  Questions about removing php, asp, html etc file extensions are all over the place and on Stack. But people always post the same answers - showing several ways to remove file extensions OR add or remove trailing slashes. I can't find a solution to my particular puzzle.

Comment: BTW RiggsFolly, you marked this a duplicate to a question I already cited in my post as not answering the question.  See "I've read through the following and many more.

Remove file extension with .htaccess: Error with trailing slash

Remove .php extension with .htaccess"

Comment: This will help clarify it I think.

I've tried making /localhost/about work by putting a php file at /localhost/about.php and by putting a php file at /localhost/about/index.php. The first one makes /localhost/about work without a trailing slash, but only if there is NO /about/ folder, so I can't then make /localhost/about/guarantee work.

If  I create an /about/ folder, the server ignores the /about.php file and looks for an index file in that folder. So, to make /localhost/about/guarantee work, I cannot have /localhost/about working.